# pandas mergeing two dataframes without duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two data frames:

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame({'Gene':['WASH7P', 'WASH7P', 'VCZ'], 'TPM':[10.034, 0.234000, 2.345]})
test2 = pd.DataFrame({'Gene':['WASH7P', 'WASH7P', 'btt'], 'TPM':[1.12345, 2.300, 0.00000]})
```

I would like to merge them into a single data frame. I have tried:

```
df = pd.merge(test1,test2, on = ['Gene'],how = 'outer')
```

resulting in:

```
    Gene    TPM_x   TPM_y
0   WASH7P  10.034  1.12345
1   WASH7P  10.034  2.30000
2   WASH7P  0.234   1.12345
3   WASH7P  0.234   2.30000
4   VCZ     2.345   NaN
5   btt     NaN     0.00000
```

However, there are row duplicates. I have tried drop_duplicates() but this does not work. The real data frames are much larger with > 30,000 rows.

The desired output:

```
    Gene    TPM_x   TPM_y
    WASH7P  10.034  1.12345
    WASH7P  0.234   2.30000
    VCZ     2.345   NaN
    btt     NaN     0.00000
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: These aren't really duplicates - the values of TPM_x and TPM_y differ in the "duplicate" rows. You should try [combine first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to drop duplicates based on column "TPM_x"

use this

```
df = pd.merge(test1,test2, on = ['Gene'],how = 'outer').drop_duplicates(keep="first", subset = 'TPM_x')
```

Comment: I found this resulted in the correct format except for TPM_y where WASH7P had only 1.2345 for both rows.